# Error importing autotable plugin for Js PDF

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm just having a miserable time trying to importing this plugin to my project.

I get the link from their GitHub
    https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable

and I add the script to the HTML head but it is not working.

```
 <script src="https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable"></script>
```

Im using js pdf without import anything and it is working but I cant use the plugin

```
function(){

      var pdf = new jsPDF();
      //This lane is not working
      //pdf.autoTable(headerTABLE, myTableArray);
      //
      pdf.addPage();
      var dataURLLogo = canvasLogo.toDataURL("image/jpeg;base64");
      var dataURLLogoSEFAC = canvasLogoSEFAC.toDataURL("image/jpeg;base64");
      var dataURLGrafica = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg;base64");

      pdf.setFontSize(25);
      pdf.setTextColor(159, 233, 96);
      pdf.setFontType('bold');
      pdf.addImage(dataURLLogo, 'jpeg', 35,25,20,20);
```

> Error: pdf.autoTable is not a function

Sorry about my english. Help please!

Comment: You can't load files from github directly. Try to load the library from your source tree.

Comment: Try to load the library form this link: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js

Comment: Tried  <script src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script> but is not working.

Comment: By the way i add <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/2.0.28/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>  and I get this js error: Mismatched anonymous define() module

Comment: It is explained in the plugin's readme how to get started in with the plugin. Have you tried that?

Comment: Ive read all the documentation about the plugin. I think I have som other script that load a lower version than jspdf.. or maybe the order in my scripts but I dont really know

Answer (score 2):

Finally I get the anwser:

just adding those two scripts BEFORE all the other scripts in m html head.

```
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF/requirejs-fix-dist/dist/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf-autotable@2.3.2"></script>
```

Thanks for all who try to help answering my question!